# adding images to drawable folder - showing blank image

Tags: android

while adding images to drawable folder using image asset i come accross this
[image: it just shows blank image .]

How to solve this issue?

Comment: may be its a large image file

Comment: simple way image copy then past in drawable

Comment: but doing that wont get it right on all the devices

Answer (score 0):

there is not any problem its the new window to add image asset android studio designed.

choose the image for asset type and give the path. then the android studio will generate different size of your image asset in different mipmap folders.

its a lot easier than before. if you dont want to use mipmap folders just copy and paste your file into youre desired folder in android studio manually.

Comment: i did that but after installing the app in my phone it is howing just a gray background

Comment: check your image extension. export it using a known application like paint or adobe photoshop to ensure that the format is right. and ensure that the file is not very very big.